# Import Node Into Custom Nodetree Python

Tags: python, add-on

I have created a custom nodetree with python and to save time I am attempting to import some existing nodes. Specifically the math node from the texture node tree "bpy.types.TextureNodeMath".

I have imported it and added it to a category, it appears in the add node menu but upon attempting to add it i get the error:

"RuntimeError: Error: Cannot add node of type TextureNodeMath to node tree 'NodeTree'
"

Any help is most appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Each "classic" node has [`poll()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Node.html#bpy.types.Node.poll) on its own editor type.

Before inserting a node, this function is first called for the node to be inserted, and if it returns a `True`, the node can be inserted.

Because TextureNodeTree.bl_idname does not equal the bl_idname of your node tree, you cannot add it.